# Switching power supply: spontaneously resetting

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, emc, switching-regulator

I have a project that uses an AC-DC switching power supply ([ECP180PS28](https://www.xppower.com/portals/0/pdfs/SF_ECP180.pdf)). The output of this supply is used directly, as well as being fed into a 5V switching power supply (based on the [LT8612](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt8612.pdf), running at ~220kHz).

I've found that there is a specific load that will cause the output of the ECP180PS28 to reset: its output will shut off for about 200ms before coming back on. The period of this reset varies between different ECP180PS28, but our worst-case unit can reset 5-6 times/minute.

The specific load is 187mA directly on the ECP180PS28, as well as 200-300mA on the 5V regulator. This is well under the maximum load for both parts. I have found that placing a metal plate connected to earth ground near the bottom of the ECP180PS28 helps reduce the frequency of the resets, but they still happen (~1 every 10-20 minutes). I'm playing with different shielding strategies and wanted to see if anyone could offer any insights.

If I either increase or decrease the load, I stop seeing these reset events.

Here's a screenshot of the reset from the oscilloscope:
[image: 28V supply reset]
In this capture:

- Yellow == 28V (Vin)
- Red == +5V (BIAS)
- Blue == SS

Here's the schematic of the power supply:
[image: circuit]
Line/Neutral are plugged directly into the supply and do not flow through the PCB.

Comment: Draw a circuit including all conducted emission precautions you have taken and, check the data sheet to see what it says about adding filters and what the maximum capacitance load can be.

Comment: I agree that radiated EM is probably not the issue here.  200ms looks suspiciously like the overcurrent hiccup timeout delay.  My guess would be the negative differential impedance of your 5V supply is causing the ECP180 to oscillate.  Do you have oscillograms of the 28V rail when it drops out?

Comment: That sounds like a typical crowbar from a slight overload. Are you suuuuuure you aren't overloading it?  Could it be having thermal problems?

Comment: @vir I've added an oscillogram to the question

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I really don't think so. This supply should be able to handle 6 amps of current. If you look at the oscilloscope shot, you can see when it shuts off, it takes some time for the load current to bring the output down

Comment: @Andyaka I've added the relevant part of the schematic. The datasheet does NOT specify maximum load capacitance, nor anything about adding filters

Comment: Kind of in line with what @vir said - either your over current or over voltage (if you have that) protection is causing the PS to shut down.  The 200 ms is probably related to the soft turn-on time of the supply.  The protection feature could easily be tripped by a noise transient.

Comment: @SteveSh If I either increase or decrease the load, I stop seeing these reset events.

Comment: What does Vin, bias and SS look like during the event?

Comment: @sbell - Hi, To eliminate the LT8612-based buck from being involved, have you tried reproducing the ECP180PS28 resets by removing that whole buck & putting an equivalent load directly on the 28 V rail? (I didn't see the specific value of the load *there* in your description, but obviously you can measure it.) My hypothesis for one possible cause is that the problem *won't* then be reproducible. Either way, it's a step forwards as either you can eliminate that buck regulator (if the resets do continue without it) or you know it's involved as part or all of the cause (if the resets stop). Thanks

Comment: @SamGibson I cannot find a way to reproduce the issue without the LT8612 being involved

Comment: @winny I've updated the o-scope capture to include the signals you asked about

Comment: I'm thinking about a resonance between SMPS onboard output caps and buck input caps, due to layout inductance, excited by buck input current. You can probe the output of the SMPS with x10 probe or coax, in AC mode, check for HF ripple, with fast scope timebase. You can use min/max mode on the display or set trigger to catch a spike.

Comment: @sbell - "*I cannot find a way to reproduce the issue without the LT8612 being involved*" - Very interesting. (a) Can we see the PCB layout? If not all, then specifically around the LT8612? How close were you able to follow the layout from the datasheet? I'm especially interested in how close the Vin capacitor(s) (2 in your case) are located to the IC, to minimise that loop. (b) What's the physical layout of the two SMPS? How far between them? (c) Can you add any more info about what you have already tried and the results of those tests? Thanks.

Comment: Did I miss something? Your input is dropping well below UVLO. Your device will restart. What’s feeding 28 V upstream?

Comment: @winny - Hi, "*Did I miss something?*" Yes, I think so (?). We know the yellow trace (28V Vin to the LT8612) drops below UVLO - but that's an effect, not a cause. The question is why does the yellow trace (which is the output of the ECP180PS28) do that? "*What’s feeding 28 V upstream?*" Based on the schematic & my interpretation of the question, it's the ECP180PS28 AC-DC supply providing a 28 V output, to the LT8612 to buck down to 5 V. Any help?

Comment: Replace the upstream power supply with something bigger, run it and capture what happens in the LT8612? Do the opposite and connect a resistor instead of LT8612 and find out what’s the problem with the ECP?